# Gold Rush and Dynamite

Tags: bang

When using the Gold Rush expansion and the dynamite is triggered to explode, does the player who played the dynamite card gain any gold? If the player has 2 life and is dealt 3 damage, would the player collect 2 or 3 gold?

Answer (score 1):

No one gets gold for damage caused by dynamite as the damage is done by the card and not by a player. Just like the sheriff would not be forced to discard all his cards if he played it when it killed a deputy. Or you would not draw cards if you played it and it killed an outlaw.